# Unable to read response from server using Socket.IO client in android

Tags: android, socket.io

I am working on an android chat application .I am not able to connect to my server using Socket.Io client in android.

**1.ChatActivity.java**

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity {
EditText edMessage;

private Socket mSocket;

{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
        Log.e("Socket", String.valueOf(mSocket));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    edMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMessage);
    String message = edMessage.getText().toString().trim();
    mSocket.connect();
  //  mSocket.emit("subscribe", "Testing");
    mSocket.on("subscribe", subscribe);
}

private Emitter.Listener subscribe = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String room = (String) args[0];
                Log.e("Response", room);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

}

Please help me to solve the issue.I am not able to verify whether the server is connected or not .

Comment: Try to trigger events through emit and then see if it receives or not. Also, read the join_room concept in socketio